# Getting all enemies to attack the player inside a collider in unity 2d

Tags: collision, detection

I'm making a game in Unity 2D. So here's my question, If the player Triggers a collider (big area), How do I make all the enemy gameobjects inside the collider to attack the player?

I want to make it like but I don't know how to.

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        //all enemies inside this collider attack the player
    }
```

Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [OverlapAreaAll](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.OverlapAreaAll.html) to get all the enemies in an area.

```
    public LayerMask enemyLayerMask;
    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        Collider2D thisCollider = GetComponent<Collider2D>();
        Collider2D[] enemyColliders = Physics2D.OverlapAreaAll(thisCollider.bounds.min, thisCollider.bounds.max, enemyLayerMask);
        foreach(Collider2D enemyCol in enemyColliders)
        {
             Enemy enemy = enemyCol.gameObject.GetComponent<Enemy>();
             if (enemy != null)
             {
                 enemy.AttackPlayer();
             }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much